# How did Elon Musk buy Bitcoin when it is open source?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, open-source

I think the title is good enough but to elaborate more, if the code base the the whole bitcoin cryptocurrency is open and it is an open source project, basically non-profit, and not owned by anyone but community contributed, then how did Elon Musk [buy it for $1.5bn](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-55939972). Who did he buy it from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bitcoin network is a decentralized network of computers (nodes), that keeps track of bitcoin (BTC, the monetary unit). The Bitcoin network has no admin, no leader, no centralized point of control. Most nodes on the network run open-source code, most commonly [bitcoin-core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin).

So when that article reports that Elon Musk (or anyone, for that matter) has purchased $X worth of bitcoin, they're talking about buying the monetary unit(s) that the network works to keep track of, not the network itself. It makes no real sense to say that *"someone bought the network"*.

Comment: Yes, it makes a lot sense now. Thanks a lot